# AndroidAnnotations library fails to use classes generated by requery

Tags: android, android-annotations, android-apt

I want to extract some part of my app to a library but AndroidAnnotations won't let me ;-)

If I have:

```
App
    - uses AndroidAnnotations
    - uses requery
```

Everything works OK.. but when I do something like this:

```
MyLibrary
    - uses requery

App
    - uses MyLibrary
    - uses AndroidAnnotations
    - uses requery
```

AnndroidAnnotations classes can't be generated because annotation processor can't find models from App requery (requery models from MyLibrary are OK).

Stacktrace is clear, usual stuff.
A lot of "error: cannot find symbol" for generated classes with _ and few "cannot find symbol" of classes generated by requery.

stacktrace

```
C:\Users\TEST\Workspace\app\src\main\java\com\example\ActivityMain.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.network.NetworkService_;
                          ^
symbol:   class NetworkService_
location: package com.example.network

C:\Users\TEST\Workspace\app\src\main\java\com\example\ActivityMain.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.data.TestModelFromRequery;
                       ^
symbol:   class TestModelFromRequery
location: package com.example.data
```

androidannotations.txt

```
17:59:02.343 [Daemon worker Thread 6] ERROR o.a.i.r.ProjectRClassFinder:47 - The generated pl.mp.empendium.debug.R class cannot be found
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':appbase')

    compile 'io.requery:requery:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.requery:requery-android:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'io.requery:requery-processor:1.1.0'

    //AndroidAnnotations
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$aaVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$aaVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$aaVersion"
}
```

I've tried with "annotationProcessor", "provided", with older gradle plugin versions and apt and nothing seems to help here. 
Classes are generated (I can see them as files) and visible by IDE, ready to be used.

I'm pretty sure this problem does not involve R file. Library doesn't have any resource and app compiled just fine before split.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you solve the issue finally?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell AA that your are running it on a [library project](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Library-projects#recognising-library-projects). 
If it does not help, you can also explicitely set the package name.
You you can do it like this:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ['resourcePackageName': 'pl.mp.empendium',
                             'library': 'true']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can read in the wiki linked above, there is one problem with library projects: the ids in the generated `R` class are not final, so you cannot use them in annotations. To work around this problem, you can set the ids as string constants:

```
@Click(resName = "myButton2")
```

Alternatively, you can use a [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects) to generate final `R` ids and use those.

Comment: @mateusz-jablonski did it help you? I've tried these settings but it didn't resolve similar issue for me, errors were the same.

Comment: @yetanothercoder Yes it helped me, I've used `resName` in the library and the weird combination of annotationProcessorOptions settings in build.gradle.
main app build.gradle  `arguments = ['resourcePackageName': 'com.example',  'library': 'true']` and library `arguments = ["library": "true", "generateFinalClasses" : "false"]`